# pipelinedb Continuous Views xxx_mrel NUMERIC to bytea?

Tags: pipelinedb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCrp4.png)I ran into a problem with pipelinedb.

There is a NUMERIC type field in the Continuous Views I built, but the mrel table generated in pipelinedb is bytea. Why is this?

Have you met? There is a good solution. Thank you

Here is the photos：

[This is the result of the two columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCrp4.png)

[This is the difference between the two columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkju5.png)

Comment: If you can post actual code, what error you are getting, and what you are expecting, people will be able to help you much better.

Comment: Thank you for your reminding. You can see the next two pictures

Answer (score 0):

Materialization tables (`<cv name>_mrel>`) store all of the state necessary to incrementally update aggregate values. These are called "transition" values. For example, to incrementally update an average, both the item count and sum must be stored; storing the average itself is not sufficient.

Some of these transition values are encoded as `bytea`. There is then an "overlay" view on top of the materialization table that "finalizes" the transition value at read time to give you the up-to-date aggregate value.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I know why it's a byte. But I still confuse how to get data in bytes. Just cv?